# metrics available for user personal reports

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

we're trying to do some basic analysis of personal reports for our org- like the distribution of reports made from one profile vs all the others, or even an org wide count. Really anything....

Is there anyway to get some analytics when it comes to personal reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from SF:

even by using the MetaData API- you can't do squat. The only thing you can do is log in as the  user, and  get the number of reports by counting the number they have in their personal folders. Thats provided you have access to login as that user

Ew Salesforce. Just ew.